# Why my code not recognizing the file type?

Tags: php

I am new to php. I  am writing a php script which will take only `c`, `cpp` and `java` files and upload them to a server.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST["file_submit"]))
    {
        $allowed_xtensions = array("c","cpp","java");
        $tmp_xtension_array = explode(".",$_FILES["file_name"]["name"]);
        $xtension = end($tmp_xtension_array);

        $type =  $_FILES["file_name"]["type"];


        if((($type == "text/x-java-source") || ($type == "text/x-csrc") || ($type == "text/x-c")) && in_array($xtension,$xtensions))
        {
            if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                exit( "Unable to process file.\nError : ".$_FILES["file_name"]["error"]);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!file_exists("/code/test.",$xtension))
                {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"],"/code/test.",$xtension) == false)
                    {
                        exit("Unable to process the file.\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit("Invalid File.");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $file_form = '  <html>
                <body>

                <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file"> Select File : </label>
                <input type="file" name="file_name" id="file_id"/><br />
                <input type="submit" name="file_submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

                </body>
                </html>';

        echo $file_form;

    }
?>
```

But whenever I upload c,cpp or java files, I get `INVALID FILE` in response, although I have uploaded the correct file. Can anyone tell me why my code is showing this behaviour?

Comment: Many serversadmins reject sourcecode files by themselves due to security issues. Do you use a hosted server or a local server like xampp?

Comment: I think you are checking MIME type with string pattern.

Comment: Btw: i got a lot of trouble checking multiple conditions with `||`. Did you try seperate them, so one condition for each type?

Comment: @YUNOWORK m using local server and yes i tried it but it is not working.

Comment: The server might not recognize the files' MIME types like you have them, e.g. it might think they're just `text/plain`. I'd prefer just matching the end of the filename with the extensions. That is probably what the server is doing to get the MIME type.

Comment: @Kannan then can u tell me how should i compare ?

Comment: @Pietu1998 can u tell me how i should compare MIME types then ?

Comment: You don't have to, just check the extension. Also Axel already seems to have answered your question.

Comment: $_FILES["file"]["name"] using you can get uploaded file name. Check extension of this file with C,JAVA etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't that be

```
 ... && in_array($xtension,$allowed_xtensions) ...
```

instead of

```
 .... && in_array($xtension,$xtensions) ...
```

Otherwise, second parameter isn't an array and you might get an error on that and it's always false?

Comment: thanx @Axel Amthor ....so stupid i am , i wasted more than 1:30 hrs only for googling y it is not working , thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your variable $type is not being set.

As a test, you might want to stick in this statement near the beginning of your script:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

I suspect that there is no key ['file']['type'] in what's being passed to your script (or at least the values aren't what you're expecting). You can also test for existence using `isset($_FILES['file']['type'])`.

It is also possible that $_FILES is empty. If it is, then try adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag and make sure file uploads are enabled.